# Validate form field to make sure it is not empty

Tags: forms, validation, asp-classic

Everyone i am newbie to ASP, I wrote a code that should take the input from HTML form.

I have given one textbox that text box value is mandatory. If user doesn't give input to the field. the asp page should show the message that "**The field cannot be left empty!**"

I have written a code, but I am not getting the output. Can anyone help me?

My code snippet is

**index.html**

```
 <form method="post" action="a1.asp">
   Field 1<input type="text" name="field1">*
   </br></br><input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
   <input type="reset" name="clear" value="clear">
   </form>
```

**a1.asp**

```
 <%
Function Mandatory(field1)
if field1 = "" then
response.write("Field one is mandatory!cannot be left empty")
else
response.write("Welcome to new html")
End if
End Function
%>
```

Comment: the "new to asp" is not the same as "I do not know nothing about asp".  First learn, then get some existing examples that runs, and then make them to fit what you try to do.

Comment: please change the question title to some thing more **meaningful**

Answer (score 2):

you must use Request.Form to get the value from "POST" action.

like:

```
field1 = request.form("field1")
if field1 = "" then 
....
```

refer to this: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_form.asp

by the way, asp is very very old. if you want to learn web develop languages, you can try ASP.NET or php.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without more information. But you need to call the function somewhere, and reference the Request collection, like:

```
<% Mandatory(Request("field1")) %>
```